# Android - MediaStore download does not work on API level 28 or lower

Tags: android, kotlin, capacitor, mediastore, android-9.0-pie

I'm writing a piece of Android code which stores a file in the user's download folder.

```kotlin
@CapacitorPlugin(name = "Downloads")
class DownloadsPlugin : Plugin() {
    @PluginMethod(returnType = PluginMethod.RETURN_NONE)
    fun download(call: PluginCall) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val filename = call.getString("fileName")!!
            val data = call.getString("data")!!

            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            }

            val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
            val uri =
                contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues)!!
            val outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)!!

            outputStream.write(data.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        }

        call.resolve()
    }
}
```

The code I've written works correctly on Android 10 (API level 29) or higher. On API level 28 or lower, the code does not work. On calling the `download` method, the following error is logged:

```
2022-10-08 16:10:59.064 23121-23184/com.example.example E/Capacitor: Serious error executing plugin
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.invoke(PluginHandle.java:125)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$com-getcapacitor-Bridge(Bridge.java:706)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:8)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no path was provided when inserting new file
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1587)
        at com.example.example.DownloadsPlugin.download(DownloadsPlugin.kt:36)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.invoke(PluginHandle.java:125) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$com-getcapacitor-Bridge(Bridge.java:706) 
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:8) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

How can I correct this error so that the code works on API level 28 or lower?

Comment: You did not post code for below Q.

Comment: `mediastore-download-does-not-work-on-api-level-28-or-lower` Well your problem has nothing to do with downloading. Please make a better subject.